The 'Discussion' section of my PBIs in Azure are hidden from me. I cannot see them but by coworkers still can
The 'Discussion' section of the PBI displays only the header and everything below it is blank white space!  All of my prior discussion data won't display for me, but my coworker can pull up the same PBI and all of the prior discussion points are visible to them.  Have I inadvertently changed a setting to cause this?
I tried exiting and relaunching the program and even tried rebooting my computer.  I'm guessing there is some setting that I had changed by complete accident and need to find a way to put it back!

Hi there, Welcome to SO. Can you please share some screenshots to help understand the issue? You mentioned you relaunched the program but what program you were using to view the PBI item Discussion. Have your tried to visit the PBI work item in your browser, and does it display any discussion there? Besides, does the issue only affect one single work item or all the work items? Have you test to check the Discussion of other work items, work item types and work items from different projects?

When sharing the information, please don't forget to remove any sensitive or private information such as token, password, certificate, IP etc. since the community is visible to public. Thx.

Sounds like a permissions / configuration issue, so not really about software development.

I figured out what had happened!  It was the little toggle button that I had accidentally clicked which hides the 'Discussion' section for ALL of my PBIs. While it's understandable a user may want to hide this section in the PBI they are actively viewing, it's crazy that it hid this section for ALL of my PBIs which made me panic because I rely on all the notes I enter there!

Thanks for taking time to share the answer to toggle the button to expand discussion section. Have a nice weekend.
